# Is there any negative impact with similar page titles and descriptions on similar sites?

Tags: seo, geotargeting, geotagging

Currently we have Canadian versions of some websites.  We are going to create some American versions, which essentially have everything the same, except the search results are geo-specific to the USA.

The format for the results page title and descriptions will remain the same, ie

{0} in {1} | Find more {0} etc etc etc... {1}.

The search term will most-likely be the same between both sites.

Will the relative similarity in the page titles and descriptions between the CDN and USA sites have any negative SEO impact, where the geo location would be the most significant difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, whole action of indexing search pages for search is a true violation of Google guidelines:

> Use robots.txt to prevent crawling of search results pages or other
>   auto-generated pages that don't add much value for users coming from
>   search engines.